# LWC Component parameter in Tab changes from Integer to String on browser refresh

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a LWC component wrapped in an Aura Component that is then configured as a Lightning Component tab. This tab is opened on a button click from the home page (in a Lightning Console) using the lightning:workspaceAPI. When opening the Component in a tab, an Integer parameter is also passed along by creating a Pagereference type of 'standard__Component'. What i'm seeing is that once the tab is opened, if the user refreshes the browser, the type of the parameter changes from Integer to String. Why is this happening ? What can be done to maintain the parameter as an Integer ?

Sample code (Please run in a Lightning Console):

Component that opens up the Tab-

**componentOnPageAura.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
    <lightning:button label="Open Component in Tab (Aura)" onclick="{!c.openComponentInTab}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**componentOnPageAuraController.js**

```
({
    openComponentInTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspace = component.find("workspace");
        var param = 12345678;
        var compPageReference = {
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__componentInTabAuraWrapper'
            },
            state: {
                c__param: param
            }
        };
        workspace.openTab({
            pageReference : compPageReference,
            focus : true
        });
    }
})
```

**componentInTabAuraWrapper.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="param" type="Integer" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
    <c:componentInTab param="{!v.param}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**componentInTabAuraWrapperController.js**

```
({
    onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
        var param = myPageRef.state.c__param;
        component.set("v.param", param);
    }
})
```

**componentInTab.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <p>{param} is of type {paramType}</p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**componentInTab.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ComponentInTab extends LightningElement {
    @api param;
    get paramType(){
        return typeof this.param;
    }
}
```

**componentInTab.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected. Parsing values from the URL will always be a string, as the data type isn't encoded in the URL parameter. They are numbers only when they don't end up going through the URL (e.g. when used in `NavigationMixin`). You should always use `parseInt`/`parseFloat` before using a (potentially) user-supplied value from the URL, if you're expecting a number to begin with. These methods are safe to use even if the number is already a number and not a string.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !